# Getting a bunch of errors when adding a Swing Menu Bar

Tags: java, macos, swing, netbeans

I am creating a Java application using NetBeans so I am taking advantage of the GUI Builder, but whenever I try to add a swing Menu Bar, I get a ton of errors. Could you help me out with this?

When in the GUI builder under the menu "Swing Menus" I drag the "Menu Bar" to the top of my JFrame (I have enough space for it and everything) and it looks fine in the GUI Builder (view links below for screenshots).

***GUI Builder Menu Bar selection***
[image]

***JFrame in the GUI Builder before adding Menu Bar***
[image]

***JFrame in the GUI Builder after adding Menu Bar***
[image]

***JFrame after running the app after adding Menu Bar***
[image]

***JFrame after running the app before adding Menu Bar***
[image]

These are all the errors I get when I run the app with the Menu Bar in it

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaMenuPainter.paintMenuBarBackground(AquaMenuPainter.java:149)
    at java.desktop/com.apple.laf.AquaMenuBarUI.paint(AquaMenuBarUI.java:82)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3926)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @HasithaMJayawardana please don't advise newbies to post 'the code'. They should post an MRE / SSCCE. Note that `[mre]` is not only less typing than 'the code', but it also auto-expands to [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled a bit and found that (based on the exception) that it caused by the look & feel. Not sure why it only fails when a menubar is added...

Please try to set the look and feel in the main method to something else like below. For me the netbeans always generates the main method to use nimbus l&f.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ...//all other stuff which was there earlier...e.g. java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()...

    }
```

Or instead of Nimbus you can try:

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```